# Add attributes existing Autocad block with python

Tags: python-3.x, attributes, win32com, autocad, autocad-scripts

I have multiple autocad files with tons of blocks already defined. I would like to write a python script that for each file adds 3 new attributes to each block.

I tried the following code:

```
import win32com.client
import pandas as pd
from pyautocad import Autocad, aDouble

acad = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")

doc = acad.ActiveDocument  # Document object
for entity in acad.ActiveDocument.ModelSpace:
    name = entity.EntityName
    if name == 'AcDbBlockReference':
        HasAttributes = entity.HasAttributes
        if HasAttributes:
            entity.AddAttribute(50, 0, "test", aDouble(200, 100, 0), "TEST", "TEST TEXT")
```

Even if it should be in the pyautocad library, AddAttribute is not recognized apparently, indeed I receive the

```
AttributeError: <unknown>.AddAttribute. Did you mean: 'GetAttributes'?
```

I am not interested in getting attributes, I would like to define new ones. Probably I should use win32com library but i feel lost. Any suggestions to fix it?

**UPDATE**

Here the correct code:

```
from pyautocad import Autocad, aDouble

acad = Autocad(create_if_not_exists=True)
doc = acad.ActiveDocument
blocks = acad.ActiveDocument.Blocks
print(blocks.ObjectName, ' number elements: ', blocks.Count)
for block in blocks:
    block.addAttribute((50, 0, "test", aDouble(200, 100, 0), "TEST", "TEST TEXT")
```

Then, launch ATTSYNC

Comment: A quick scan of the AutoCad reference here: https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-88EEBCA3-8AF5-4776-9D54-520B05AB9129 suggests that the iteration over the `ModelSpace` returns `BlockReference` objects and *not* `Block` objects. Only the latter has the `AddAttribute` method. I've never used AutoCAD, but the documentation suggests you have to iterate over the `BlockReference` to access the 'referred-to' objects (or use `Explode`): https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-6D96780F-3EC6-447C-B341-0FE815BE9979

Comment: Do you have any clue about how access and iterate on the BlockReference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`AddAttribute`](https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2023/ENU/?guid=GUID-53417B1F-C6F1-4818-AD43-8C5F81E36BCA) method will create an Attribute *Definition*, which should belong to a Block *Definition*, not a Block *Reference* (which is one of potentially many instances of the definition inserted in the drawing at varying positions, scales, rotations & orientations).

As such, you should obtain the target Block Definition object from the Blocks Collection (`acad.ActiveDocument.Blocks`) and invoke the `AddAttribute` method on this container.

It may also be necessary to 'synchronise' the attributes held by block references with those found in the definition - this operation is performed by the standard `ATTSYNC` command in AutoCAD.

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. So, i created blocks but I receive the ` AttributeError: <unknown>.AddAttribute` .
Sorry my remarks and code may seem banal, but I am absolutely new to autocad

` from pyautocad import aDouble
import win32com.client
acad = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")

doc = acad.ActiveDocument  # Document object
blocks= acad.ActiveDocument.Blocks
res = blocks.AddAttribute(50, 0, "test", aDouble(200, 100, 0), "TEST", "TEST TEXT") `

Comment: You are invoking `AddAttribute` on the Blocks Collection, not a single block definition - you need to obtain the Block Definition from the Blocks Collection.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to iterate inside the blocks collection for extracting the block definition?

Comment: I saw that my variable blocks is now a AcDbBlockTable, where I can apply the following methods https://help.autodesk.com/view/OARX/2023/ENU/?guid=OARX-RefGuide-__MEMBERTYPE_Methods_AcDbBlockTable , but I am still not succesfull in extracting the single block definitions succesfully.

Comment: You can either iterate over the block definitions using a `for` loop (e.g. `for block in acad.ActiveDocument.Blocks:`) or use the `item` method to obtain the block definition directly from the collection.

Comment: So, my mistake was using win23.com library. If I call the autocad file with `acad = Autocad(create_if_not_exists=True)` it works, if I do it with `acad = win32com.client.Dispatch("AutoCAD.Application")` , even if the name of the object is correctly identified as a BlockTable, the type is unknown. Now I should see how to launch the ATTSYNC on my script. Thank you for your support.